# How to use the Google Apps Script code for creating a Draft email (from 985)?

Tags: email, google-apps-script

In [Issue 985](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=985), a developer named "yurec" (perhaps) in comment #29 provides some code to create a draft (text) email in Google Apps Script. Some others thank him for the good work and say that it's tested and working.

I'm a bit stumped as to how to use it and which parts of the code need changing (like "id" and "threadId"?).

Anyway, ideally I guess the usage would be like:

MailApp.createDraft(emailTo, subject, body, {'name':'Bob from Example Ltd'});

But whatever works is good with me. Thanks for any help here. Getting this to work will be fantastico.

### Working Code - You just need to set up the Gmail API as per the selected answer

```
function createDraft() {

  var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount(); // needed for auth scope

  var raw = 
      'Subject: testing Draft\n' + 
      'To: my.test.account@gmail.com\n' +
      'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=1234567890123456789012345678\n' +
      'testing Draft msg\n' + 
      '--1234567890123456789012345678--\n';

  var draftBody = Utilities.base64Encode(raw);

  var params = {method:"post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
                muteHttpExceptions:true,
                payload:JSON.stringify({
                "message": {
                "raw": draftBody
              }
            })
           };
```

Comment: I copied the code from that post into an Apps Script script file, and the "id" and "threadId" text is stuff that is commented out of the code.  It's not code to be used, it's an example of what the return value of the `UrlFetchApp.fetch("");` HTTP Request statement is.

Comment: There is no `createDraft` method of the `MailApp` Class.  [Documentation MailApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app)  If you want to call the createDraft function that is shown in the post you are referencing, you would simply do that as you would call any JavaScript function.  And there are no arguments in that createDraft function to pass anything to.  You could add arguments, but that's just basic programming knowledge.

Comment: lol, yeah I get it now. But bummer, it didn't work. The Unread email count is correct and each value seems to be read correctly (via the debug window) but unfortunately no draft.

Comment: Agh, checked the logs which reminded me that the Gmail API needs activating. :-)

Comment: Now I see that there is Users.drafts class in the Gmail API (https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts). What steps would I need to take to get this up and running? Bounty awaiting ~

Comment: Oh, sick - it's working. So happy. This opens up all sorts of possibilities for our business automation. No bounty required, never mind...

Comment: @GreggCleland Then please delete your question. I lost a lot of time reading this until I saw this hidden comment!

Comment: @Henrique: Sry for that; change made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to setup the Gmail API in the console

***In Script Editor:***

- **Resources** > **Advanced Script Services** *(screenshot 1)*
- click on **Google Developers Console** link at the bottom of the window
  *(screenshot 2)*

***In Developers Console:***

- Scroll down and find **Gmail API** and turn it on. *(screenshot 3)*

Close the **Developers Console** tab

Click **Ok** in the **Advanced Google Services** modal

Authorize the app, and you're all set.

---

Here is the code I tested with

```
function createDraft() {
  try{
  var forScope = GmailApp.getInboxUnreadCount(); // needed for auth scope

  var raw = 
      'Subject: testing Draft from Apps Script\n' + 
      //'To: cyrus@mydomain.net\n' +
      'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=1234567890123456789012345678\n' +
      'testing Draft msg\n' + 
      '--1234567890123456789012345678--\n';

  var draftBody = Utilities.base64Encode(raw);

  var params = {method:"post",
                contentType: "application/json",
                headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
                muteHttpExceptions:true,
                payload:JSON.stringify({
                  "message": {
                    "raw": draftBody
                  }
                })
               };

  var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts", params);
  Logger.log(resp.getContentText());
  }catch(err){
    Logger.log(err.lineNumber + ' - ' + err);
  }
}
```

Screenshot 1
[image: Advanced Services Menu]

Screenshot 2
[image: Advanced Services Modal]

Screenshot 3
[image: Developers Console]

Comment: Cheers Cyrus. I managed to stumble my way thru it but hope it'll be useful for someone else. And the bounty is yours!

Answer (score 0):

is it any solutions, to paste on this e-mail part of sheet?
f.e.:

spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Podsumowanie - raport'), true);
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:N46');